# Attempting to calculate cost when button is clicked - value not updating

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've coded a simple ordering system where you 'select' an integer from a number input, and then when you click on an 'update' button, it alters the inner text of a paragraph element below it. However, I've tried two methods:

1. plain JavaScript for orderQuantity - innerHTML doesn't update
2. parseInt for orderQuantity - returns £NaN in innerHTML

Please can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

Here's the code:

```js
let orderQuantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("order-stepper").value);
let orderText = document.getElementById("order-value");
let orderValue = 2.50;
let orderAmount =  orderValue * orderQuantity;
let updateButton = document.getElementById("order-update");

function update() {
  orderText.innerHTML = ("Total cost: £" + orderAmount);
}

updateButton.addEventListener("click", update);
```

```css
.order-stepper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.order-stepper label {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 30px 20px;
}

.order-stepper input {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #999;
}

.order-price {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#order-value {
  font-size: 28px;
}

#order-update {
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border: 3px solid #e2979c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#order-update:hover {
  background-color: #e2979c;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-stepper">
          <label for="quantity">Select your quantity</label>
          <input id="order-stepper" type="number" name="quantity" value="" max="3">
        </div>
        <button id="order-update" type="button" name="button">Update</button>
        <div class="order-price">
          <h2 id="order-value">Total cost: £0</h2>
        </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: calculation should go inside the `update()` function otherwise it will always _update_ with the already calculated old value

Comment: Thanks - you're right. Knew it was simple haha! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

You should move the variables inside the function. The variables have been initialized just once and are not updating with the changing value of the text box so you don't get any value when you click update.

```js
let updateButton = document.getElementById("order-update");

function update() {
    let orderQuantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("order-stepper").value);
    let orderText = document.getElementById("order-value");
    let orderValue = 2.50;
    let orderAmount =  orderValue * orderQuantity;

  orderText.innerHTML = ("Total cost: £" + orderAmount);
}

updateButton.addEventListener("click", update);
```

```css
.order-stepper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.order-stepper label {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 30px 20px;
}

.order-stepper input {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #999;
}

.order-price {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#order-value {
  font-size: 28px;
}

#order-update {
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border: 3px solid #e2979c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#order-update:hover {
  background-color: #e2979c;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-stepper">
  <label for="quantity">Select your quantity</label>
  <input id="order-stepper" type="number" name="quantity" value="" max="3">
</div>
<button id="order-update" type="button" name="button">Update</button>
<div class="order-price">
  <h2 id="order-value">Total cost: £0</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help :D

Answer (score 1):

I agree with putting variables inside the function.  You may be able to clean up the code and make it safer by replacing the `let`s with `const`s, using the `parseInt()` shorthand `+`, and using `element.textContent` instead of `element.innerHTML` for security.

```
document.getElementById("order-update").addEventListener("click", update);

function update() {
    const orderQuantity = +document.getElementById("order-stepper").value;
    const orderText = document.getElementById("order-value");
    const orderValue = 2.50;
    const orderAmount = orderValue * orderQuantity;
    orderText.textContent = ("Total cost: £" + orderAmount);
}
```

In addition, if you import the JS file in the head, make sure to `defer` it so it does not break your listener.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head>
```